# Is there a way to merge two tables and bringing only matching value from the second one?

Tags: python, pandas

I' have 2 tables on pandas (Table1,Table2) and I would like to get a third one (Table3) as in the example below (I feel like a visual example is worth 1000 words)

Could you please tell me how would the code work?

Table1

| ISIN | Price |
| --- | --- |
| A | 1 |
| B | 2 |
| C | 3 |
| D | 4 |

Table2

| ISIN | Price2 |
| --- | --- |
| A | 5 |
| D | 6 |
| E | 7 |

Table3

| ISIN | Price | Price2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | 5 |
| B | 2 |  |
| C | 3 |  |
| D | 4 | 6 |

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are using pandas dataframes you can use the `merge()` function

```
Table3 = Table1.merge(Table2, on='ISIN', how='left')
```

Comment: Nailed that... thanks mate